# Flow type a generic function that groups any type that has at least an ID

Tags: flowtype

I'm trying to type with Flow a function that maps As to Bs, where the only restrictions are:

- B contains an A
- A has at least an id property which is a string

Apart from that, A can be any object, and, in this situation, B is well known.
I want to type the function with a generic/polymorphic type that so the type checker knows that you will get an array of objects containing the A and B that matches.

My attempt below does not give me any type error, but I don't think it is correct either.
Will love to understand how to properly type this so you can get the most guarantees.

```
type B = {A: {id: string}}

const BContainsA = (id: string) => (b: B) =>
  b.A.id === id

type MapResult<T> = {
  AsWithBs: Array<{ A: T, B: B }>,
  AsWithoutBs: string[],
}

const mapAsToBs = <T>(
  As: { ...T, id: string }[],
  Bs: B[]
): MapResult<T> => {
  return As.reduce(
    (result, a) => {
      const b = Bs.find(BContainsA(a.id))
      if (!b) {
        result.AsWithoutBs.push(a.id)
        return result
      }
      result.AsWithBs.push({ A: a, B: b })
      return result
    },
    { AsWithBs: [], AsWithoutBs: [] }
  )
}

mapAsToBs([{pos:2,id: '1'},{pos:1,id: '11'}],[{A:{id: '1'}}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that all I had to do was to add a constraint to the generic type like this:

```js
const mapAsToBs = <T:{id: string}>(
  As: T[],
  Bs: B[]
): MapResult<T> => {

}
```

It is [indeed documented](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#generic-types-act-as-bounds-), but the syntax is so unintuitive and the explanation is so short, that I would have never guessed it just by reading it.

You can check how it works as expected [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAQlC8UDeBBAXMglgEwwZ2ACdMA7AcwF8KAoagYwHsSDYBhJ4AQ1LxQSgAUOfEVJkAlAgB8ggEYYYk+FOpQosgHQoNOBPEQ5aoSFACynMACUIeAK4AbYAB4AKjMRJVUFHgDqmYAALGDwMFEJCThAnJG8MFwAaWAUoCikErx9-IIZbYBCRYnIAbQBdDJp6JhYAWwsfFwYQ-lcMJGEoAiLKKQFM0KgXMoy1Atgy6nEMcysbB2c3aWQvQghgW0ISbzwNVexbOgg+tTUBVbtHJM4lGU8Tk8ZmYHV+EI0AM1JsARh2Ei4eCgBJwdNhxOIvPdMO9BABCWSSO73E7neZaPwBQK5fI7MC2PCBYGgiHIlFrDZbVGOSEnGikqnAdHZYK4-GE2LoKCcJIwDCyVIk5GrdabKAMmkUEYnDkYoJjYbbZnY+WlVJeCGVOpgBpNPACYpIMAMUIAJgSHQA5ABGC2Sw3GtBW824KDWm2S5BG0IATm9SWEToo5QN6HaLuttqD4iAA)